# pivot_wider column index error where spread works fine

Tags: r, tidyr

Trying to use pivot wider and seem to always get the following error even when spread easily works:

`` Error: Positive column indexes in `[` must match number of columns:
* `.data` has 1 columns ``

A trivial example

```
test
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   CaseNumber ID    count_number
        <dbl> <chr>        <int>
 1       668. A                1
 2       659. D                1
 3       661. E                1
 4       661. G                1
 5       639. B                1
 6       676. G                2
 7       728. C                1
 8       676. G                3
 9       717. F                1
10       734. H                1

pivot_wider(test, names_from = count_number, values_from = CaseNumber)

Error: Positive column indexes in `[` must match number of columns:
* `.data` has 1 columns
* Position 2 equals 6
* Position 3 equals 8
```

It doesn't matter if I include further arguments such as id_cols or values_fill, the same error occurs. I'm in R 3.6.0 and tidyverse 1.3.0. Seems like I'm missing something obvious...
In contrast spread does what I expect:

```
spread(test, count_number, CaseNumber)
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  ID      `1`   `2`   `3`
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      668.   NA    NA 
2 B      639.   NA    NA 
3 C      728.   NA    NA 
4 D      659.   NA    NA 
5 E      661.   NA    NA 
6 F      717.   NA    NA 
7 G      661.  676.  676.
8 H      734.   NA    NA
```

Comment: It is working  fine for mee

Comment: Hmmm...maybe a pull request then

Comment: I am using tidyr 1.0.0

Comment: OP followed up with this issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/830 (Hadley says gets no error). I am having the same problem, I will j just update my R version